# IVR support in firebase

Tags: firebase, ivr

Using firebase we have integrated OTP service for user to register & login in our web app. Is it possible to integrate IVR service also for users registration & login. Pointing to document reference would be helpful. I could not find one in firebase documentation.

Used Angular as front end and node as backend in our project,

Thanks,

Mohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication comes with a number of built-in providers, for email+password, many social sign-in services, and phone number based verification. But there is no built-in provider that uses interactive voice response (IVR) to sign the user in.

That said, if you have an IVR provider you want to use, you can build a custom provider to sign the user that you authentication with that service into Firebase. See the documentation for what that looks like [in your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth), and [on the back-end](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) that you'll need to create.